# Is there a working paypal module for kohana 3.2?

Tags: php, paypal, kohana

I am looking for a way to implement paypal checkout into my kohana system. I've found two modules, one by shadowhand and one fork of it. Both of them are not working properly (maybe I am doing something wrong, don't want to blame the modules)

What is the best way to implement paypal, is there something i can use or do I have to start from scratch?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried any of the modules listed at kohana-modules.com?

There are 3 [PayPal Modules](http://kohana-modules.com/search?query=paypal) listed. Haven't tried them TBH but would like to know if they worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

I just finished my PayPal module for Kohana 3.3, but should also work with 3.2

You can check it out here: https://github.com/paptamas/kohana-paypal-ipn.

You can find a well detailed Readme, to learn the basics and see how to implement it.

I hope it can help you!

Answer (score 0):

Not Kohana specific, but a while ago I created a class for handling IPN (Instant Payment Notification) and a function for dealing with PDT (Payment Data Transfer). Been wanting to package them in a handy Kohana module, but never come around to it yet. Anyways, shouldn't be difficult to stick in a Kohana project, depending on what features you require.

- PDT: [blog post](http://www.geekality.net/?p=1210), [sample and source](http://samples.geekality.net/pdt/)
- IPN: [blog post](http://www.geekality.net/?p=1420), [sample and source](http://samples.geekality.net/ipn/)

Hope it helps! And let me know if you make or find a good Kohana module for PayPal integration...